# How to add timer to the individual points added to Line2d in godot engine?

Tags: game-engine, godot

I am working on a game in which I am using a line2d. I am adding points on the line2d in the script. But I want to add timer to the individual points added in the line2d. If the timer of a point is timed out then that point should be removed. How can I do that? Can someone help please.

```
if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        if pressed:
            active_line.add_point(event.position)
            timer = Timer.new()
            timer.start(3)
            timer.connect("timeout",self,"_on_timer_timeout")
            add_child(active_line)
        
        elif !pressed:
            active_line.clear_points()
            remove_child(active_line)

func _on_timer_timeout():
    active_line.remove_point(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a simple timer in the middle of the function, I would recommend this:

```py
yield(get_tree().create_timer(2.0), "timeout")
```

The `2.0` is the amount of time you want the function to halt, and the `"timeout"` refers to the timeout signal, so after the timer has run out, the process will continue with whatever below it.